# read big data in r with read.big.matrix

Tags: r, bigdata

I am trying to get 1.36 GB data into R, somewhat above 87 million rows and two columns, both numeric. I found the `bigmemory` and related packages, however am not succeeding with it, not even with reading the data. The original data form is xyz, where I simply changed the file extenstion to txt. I guess it is space delimited.

This is my input:

```
x <- read.big.matrix("mydata.txt", type="double", header=F,backingfile="mydata.bin",descriptorfile="mydata.desc")
```

And this error message is returned:

```
Fehler in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  could not allocate memory (1024 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'
```

I also tried

```
x <- read.big.matrix("mydata.txt",header=F, type="double",sep=" ")
```

with and without specifying the separator (in which case I read, the separator is guessed). This resulted however in reading only the first column of my data.
(I don't know too much about computers, but I think the one I am working on should be fine enough - CPU 3.3GHz, RAM 8 GB?).
Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks for all hints!

Comment: What do you mean by "original data form is xyz"? is it the file extension?

Comment: It is an export from some GIS, as far as I understood, and yes, xyz is the file extension and contains x and y coordinates in two columns only. If it wasn't that big, you could simply open it in Editor or Notepad, or as I did, re-name it as txt and use it thus.